# Analyze convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+(-1)^n)^s}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'd appreciate any help analyzing the convergence of the following series:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+(-1)^n)^s}$$

Thanks,

Comment: What is $s$ here?

Comment: First, we need to know what $s$ is. You may want to expand the series and then collect certain terms, you should get something that looks like the [Riemann zeta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

Comment: @ClementC. It's supposed to be the exponent of the denominator. The excercise is about establishing conditions on s, so the series converges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One may observe that, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+(-1)^n)^s}&=\frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}\frac1{(1+(-1)^n/n)^s}\\\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}\left(1-s\frac{(-1)^n}{n} +\mathcal{O}\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}-\frac{s}{n^{1+s}} +\mathcal{O}\left(\frac1{n^{2+s}}\right)
\end{align}
$$ giving, for some large $n_0$,
$$
\sum_{n\geq n_0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+(-1)^n)^s}=\sum_{n\geq n_0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}-s\sum_{n\geq n_0}\frac1{n^{1+s}}+\sum_{n\geq n_0}\mathcal{O}\left(\frac1{n^{2+s}}\right)
$$ Thus your series is *convergent for all* $s>0$.

Comment: Damn, you were fast.

Comment: @OlivierOloa I can't seem to understand what you did after you factored out $\frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}\frac1{(1+(-1)^n/n)^s}$ how do you get that big o function? Thanks

Comment: @Meno11 I've used the fact that, as $u\to 0$: $$ \frac1{(1+u)^s}=1-s u +O(u^2)$$ To obtain this, you may just apply the Taylor expansion $f(u)=f(0)+f'(0)u+O(u^2)$ to $f(u):= \frac1{(1+u)^s}$. Thanks.